# Non-logarithmic bijective function from $\mathbb{R}^+$ into $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, transformation, fractions

I knew 2 functions that bijectively transform $(0,\infty)$ into $(-\infty,\infty)$, which are $\log x$ and $\log\log(x+1)$. Do you guys know another function like (as simple as possible) but does not involve $\log$? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any positive continuous $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that

$$\int_0^1 f(t)\, dt = \infty=\int_1^\infty f(t)\, dt.$$

Then $F(x) = \int_1^x f(t)\, dt$ has the desired property.

Proof: By the FTC, $F'(x)=f(x)>0$ for all $x.$ Hence $F$ is strictly increasing, and therefore injective. Verify that $F(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+,$ and $F(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty.$ By the IVT, $F$ maps $(0,\infty)$ onto $\mathbb R.$

This gives lots of examples. For example, we could take $f(t) = t^{-3/2} + e^t.$ The corresponding $F(x)$ is $-2x^{-1/2} +e^x +2-e.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea, actually I also need the explicit inverse function of it, so $t^{-3/2}+e^t$ is a bit difficult for me. But still I thank you, and by your idea I can look by myself

Comment: Btw, why you didn't define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ instead? and why  we need the condition $\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\infty$?

Answer (score 3):

For example, take $$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: And change it to e.g. $x-\tfrac{1}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{x}}}$ if you want its natural/maximal domain to be $\mathbb{R}^+$, like $\log$.

Comment: is that bijective? the inverse is $\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$?

Comment: $f'(x)=1+\frac{1}{x^2}>0$.

Comment: ah, strictly positive derivative, thank you guys

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki Technically, strictly positive derivative is only enough to prove injectivity. However, the fact that the derivative is always larger than $1$ means that it is surjective as well.